# How to make aliases in c++ (on assembly level)?

Tags: c++, llvm, alias

The question sounds stupid. Surely, just type:

```
  int i = 1;
  int &k = i;
```

But after I compile it with llvm ( optimization flag is `-O0` ) I have next intermediate interpretation:

```
  %i = alloca i32, align 4                        ; <i32*> [#uses=2]
  %k = alloca i32*, align 8                       ; <i32**> [#uses=2]
```

It means that `i` and `k` are not aliases (as I understand %k contains address of %i).
How to make an example of aliases?

Comment: What you have is a pointer. References are commonly implemented as pointers and dereferenced at each use.

Comment: If you compile with `-03`, good chances are the `k` variable would be optimized out.

Comment: `k` is an alias of `i`, regardless of what's generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two pointers are aliased if they point to the same memory location. The concept of aliasing is only applicable for pointers - since a non-pointer value cannot point anywhere. So in your example `i` can never alias anything.

If you want an aliasing example, look at this snippet:

```
int i = 1;
int &j = i;
int &k = i;
```

`j` and `k` are aliased.

I'm not exactly sure what you're expecting to see on the LLVM side, especially with `-O0`. If you were expecting a [global alias](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aliases), those are unrelated and used to provide a second name to an existing global.